# Maintain User Control State in UWP Application using Template 10

Tags: mvvm, uwp, template10

I am creating UWP app using Template 10. I have created user control like this.

[image]

```
 <my:DeviceInfoUserControl  OnEndpointTypeChange="{Binding OnEndpointTypeChangeCommand}" Component="{Binding DeviceManagementViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}"></my:DeviceInfoUserControl>
```

I have Radio Buttons on User Control.  I have added User Control on Multiple screens.

This user control has its own ViewModel as well as Some Dependency Properties as follows:

```
public class DeviceManagementViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

}
public sealed partial class DeviceInfoUserControl : UserControl
{
    public bool IsToggled = true;
    public DeviceInfoUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OnEndpointTypeChangeProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(
          "OnEndpointTypeChange",
          typeof(ICommand),
          typeof(DeviceInfoUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand OnEndpointTypeChange
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(OnEndpointTypeChangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OnEndpointTypeChangeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComponentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Component", typeof(DeviceManagementViewModel), typeof(DeviceInfoUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DeviceManagementViewModel Component
    {
        get { return (DeviceManagementViewModel)GetValue(ComponentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ComponentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I want to preserve Radio Button Selection across all screens. How should I achieve this?

Comment: So do you want to select a radiobutton on all control in a single click?

Comment: Yes... Something like view model  which can be accessible globally... So that if I checked radio button its selection will get reflected to everywhere

Comment: SessionState its built into the ViewModelBase

Comment: You are going to want something like an EventAggregator to pass messages around.  check out Mvvm Light example as well as the Messaging Sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know its better way or not but I have achieved this by making Singletone Viewmodel.

```
 public class DeviceManagementViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
    public static readonly DeviceManagementViewModel _instance = new DeviceManagementViewModel ();
    private DeviceManagementViewModel ()
    {

    }
/*Properties and Methods */

}
```

In Parent Screen ViewModel I have created following property

```
 private DeviceManagementViewModel  _deviceManagementViewModel;
        public DeviceManagementViewModel DeviceManagementViewModel1
        {
                    get { return _deviceManagementViewModel; }
                    set { Set(ref _deviceManagementViewModel, value); }
        }
```

I have Instantiated property in Constructor:

```
  public ConfigurationViewModel()
  {
    DeviceManagementViewModel1 = DeviceManagementViewModel._instance;
  }
```

And on User Control:

```
<my:DeviceInfoUserControl  OnEndpointTypeChange="{Binding OnEndpointTypeChangeCommand}"  Component="{Binding DeviceManagementViewModel1,Mode=TwoWay}"></my:DeviceInfoUserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the same ViewModel instance is used for all control instance. The XAML way is always create new instance:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:DetailPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

In the Template10's `Bootstrapper` class with the `ResolveForPage` method override, you can inject ViewModel's after the page navigation through a custom logic, or through dependency injection [LINK](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Bootstrapper#dependency-injection)